# How to ensure that the Android adView is always displayed after the bottom of the last item in my Android listView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Here's the `activity_results` XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.test.ResultsActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.test.test.ResultsActivity">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"></ListView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And, here's the `content_results.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/def"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ghi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have the `adView` item at the bottom of the last element of the `listView`. Is this possible with the layouts I currently have? Because it looks like the `adView` in the `activity_results` has no relation to the list items in the `content_results` file?

I've also tried `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` attribute to position the `adView` below the `ListView`, but there seems to be no change.

Please let me know if you can catch any other basic errors in these layouts?

Comment: Hi, you need to add AdView as a last item right? For example if you have 20 items in list and the 21st item is adview? If yea, you can do with list or recycler adapter add the last item as null or empty value and you have to add all ads related logic in adapter class.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want that. I actually want the adView in the container activity (activity_results, which contains that listView) - so one adView per page regardless of whether the listView has items or not.

Comment: In that case, the adview won’t show after the last time. It will show once the activity open…. You can your linear layout or constraint layout.

Comment: Is your "adView" covered by "listView"?

Comment: @UrvishShiroya I'd say the adView is on top of the last item of the listView.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping up co-ordinator view group with constraintLayout and putting adview outside of this co-ordinator viewgroup and constrain adview to bottom to the activity layout so that ad view is independent of list view's data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.test.ResultsActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.test.test.ResultsActivity">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"></ListView>

            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if still overlaps , use margins accordingly on co-ordinator layout (marginBottom ="10dp" for example)

Answer (score -1):

I have two pieces of advice for you:

1. **Avoid using ListView** (unless you have a fixed amount and few items). Prefer RecyclerView which is so much more performative. Basically, if you have so many items, with RecyclerView, just a certain amount of items will have the layout rendered. With ListView, even the hundredth item will have the layout rendered (even if you can see just the first four items on your screen at a certain moment).
2. **Take care about using several nested view groups**. It impacts the performance to render the layout on the device. In general, just a root ConstraintLayout solves all the problems you can face to align the elements.
   For the first layout, because the AppBarLayout needs the CoordinatorLayout to work properly, you can keep the CoordinatorLayout as root and use ConstraintLayout after the AppBarLayout. For the second layout, the same thing. Here is an example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/def"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/abc"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ghi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/def"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

About your problem with the AdView position, try something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:itemCount="@integer/material_motion_duration_long_2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Let me know if it worked. If you need some more help, contact me.